# Reading chunks of line from text file into strings

Tags: c++, string, text, ifstream

So say if I have this line in a text file.

```
AarI/CACCTGCNNNN'NNNN/'NNNNNNNNGCAGGTG//
```

What I want is to read this line into a string until the forwardslash appears and then start reading the next set of characters into another string.. So in this example I would have 3 strings containing

```
string1 =  "AarI"
string2 = "CACCTGCNNNN'NNNN"
string3 = "'NNNNNNNNGCAGGTG"
```

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: Why not read the entire string into memory and then split it?

Comment: Yes - Sit down and write code. We are not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

`istream::getline()` with a delim character of '/' - see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

Not the best or safest, probably amongst the simpler approaches.

Comment: Better to `std::getline` into a string instead of using C strings.

Comment: Of course, and then use the `.getline(..., '/')` on the string buffer.

Comment: You can use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) which reads into a `std::string` directly, using a delimiter character.

Comment: Indeed, without a doubt that would be the dead simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sstream`. The code below shows an example of how to split a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string str, char delimiter);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  string DNAstr = "AarI/CACCTGCNNNN'NNNN/'NNNNNNNNGCAGGTG//";
  vector<string> splittedlines = split(DNAstr, '/');

  for(int i = 0; i < splittedlines.size(); ++i)
    cout <<""<<splittedlines[i] << " \n";

  return 0;
} 


vector<string> split(string str, char delimiter) {
  vector<string> buffer;
  stringstream ss(str); 
  string tok;

  while(getline(ss, tok, delimiter)) {
    buffer.push_back(tok);
  }

  return buffer;
}
```